# make CSS nav bar cover top

Tags: html, css, navigation, nav

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets\sets1.css">
 </head>
 <style type="text/css"> 
body                                                                   /* site bg color    */
     {
     margin: 0; 
     background-color:#b0c4de
     }

 #navbar ul { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 5px; 
    cellspacing: 0;
    cellpadding: 0;
    border: 0;
    list-style-type: none; 
    background-color: #8B008B; 
    } 

#navbar ul li {  
    display: inline; 
    } 

#navbar ul li a { 
    text-decoration: none; 
    padding: .2em 1em; 
    color: white; 
    background-color: #8B008B; 
    } 

#navbar ul li a:hover { 
    color: #0EC6D7; 
    background-color: #8B008B; 
    } 

</style> 
</head> 
 <body> 
  <div id="navbar"> 
     <ul> 
     <li><a href="http://"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Site Logo" height="50" width="68"></img></a></li> 
     <li><a href="#">Forum's</a></li> 
     <li><a href="#">Chat's</a></li> 
     <li><a href="#">Login</a></li> 
     <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li> 
  </ul> 
</div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

added margin: 0;  to body tag and it works like fb header covering whole top of page no white space or ignorant breaking or any thing like that also its cross browser so thanks alot .thank all you users who have helped me with this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the margin to 0px in the body

```
 body{
 margin:0px;
 background-color:#b0c4de
 }
```

This will remove any white spaces around the body

If you want the navigation bar to span the top of the entire page try setting the width to 100%

```
 #navbar{
 position:relative;
 width:100px;
 height:auto;
 background-color: #8B008B; 
 }
```

This will make a Magenta bar across the top of the page. Not sure about what height you want so I get it to auto so it will re-size depending on the content. You can then place your logo image inside this div.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean a "sticky" header then use position:fixed

```
#navbar{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

You may need to define width, z-index, or anything else specific to your design, but this is the basic idea.

If you didn't mean sticky, then maybe william got the answer right.

Comment: This will create a sticky header - is that what he wants?

Comment: you know, you're right. I just assumed he wanted sticky because I hadn't figured the possibility that someone didn't know how to just align the nav to the top of the page... If you run his code as is in a jsfiddle it displays as a normal header would, no white space.

Answer (score -1):

You need to put `margin: 0;` in the body tag. I recommend to use a reset style that you can find in google to reset all spaces that browsers put.